# How to animate an object on a wavy path

Tags: jquery

Using jquery, how to make the object move in a wavy path, horizontally, where the height of the waves is gradually decreasing!

Comment: You would have to use `animate()` inside of a loop. It would be better to use CSS3 transitions and animations.

Comment: @BenM Can u help by posting the code?

Comment: Please see my answer. It has a demonstration link that should be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use TweenMax 'engine'.
You can then write literally one line of code.

```
TweenMax.to(img, 5, {css:{bezier:{type:"soft", values:[{x:250, y:250}, {x:350, y:0}, {x:400, y:100}], autoRotate:false}}, ease:Power1.easeInOut});
```

Sample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JujpX/).

(You may want to tweak the curve...)

Or, [without using 'bezier'](http://jsfiddle.net/v99SA/):

```
TweenMax.to(img, 5, {x: 300, ease:Power1.easeInOut});
TweenMax.to(img, 5, {y: 150, ease:Elastic.easeOut.config(3, 0.15)});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you could achieve this using jQuery's `animate()` function inside of a loop, but that isn't great.

You should look into using CSS3 transitions and animations. Here's a useful start point > http://csspathanimation.calyptus.eu/

Comment: The code s too long, I just need 5 seconds animation, thnx for the help, but it would be tedious

Comment: The code was just a sample. You need to play around with the settings, and define your own path. Click on the Circle to see a more simplified version.

Comment: But did u really go through the full code on the right hand side??

Comment: Yes. What's the problem? That's how CSS animation works. There is no shortcut I'm afraid, and no-one here is going to write it for you.

Comment: The thing would be accomplished with css only?? no other jquery alternative

Comment: Yes, as I said there is a jQuery alternative, but it requires animation in loops and would be quite laggy on older, lower-end machines. CSS animations are HW-accelerated on certain devices, so it's the way forward.

Comment: ur help too appreciated, but the simplest way is to animate  along the sine curve, gradually decreasing the height, thats what I found, anyways thanx a lot